# Adding the rows of a column into another column per row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a query that creates a column that adds all the row value of the previous column per row. I've tried SUM and COUNT but this is not giving me the result I want. How should I tackle this problem?

```
+----+------+-----+
| id |amount|total|
+----+------+-----+
| 1  | 10   | 10  |
| 2  | 20   | 30  |
| 3  | 15   | 45  |
| 4  | 30   | 75  |
+----+------+-----+
```

Comment: what is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: Version is 10.2.17-MariaDB-10.2.17
the expected output would be 
the total colum in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Rolling Sum problem. In MySQL 8.0.2 and above, you can solve this using [Window functions with Frames](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html). In older versions, we can do the same using User-defined Session variables.

Try:

```
SELECT 
  dt.id, 
  dt.amount, 
  @tot := @tot + dt.amount AS total 
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    id, 
    amount
  FROM your_table_name 
  ORDER BY id
) AS dt 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @tot := 0) AS user_init
```